# How to configure Rails Assets pipeline to use Formtastic's css

Tags: ruby-on-rails

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*= require formtastic
```

I get this error:

```
rake assets:precompile 
/Users/Nerian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/ruby /Users/Nerian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@davinci/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "= require formt..."
  (in /Users/Nerian/Projects/davinci/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/Nerian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/b...]
```

So the rake task doesn't work, but strangely when I run the app in development the assets are compiled since I can see the formtastic css being applied.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
 *= require formtastic
 *= require my_formtastic_changes
*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that line inside a comment group?  It should be:

```
/*
*= require formtastic
*/
```

I don't think development mode compiles the files, but rather serves them separately, so that may explain why there's no error at that time...

Comment: It was there outside a comment group. I put them now inside and now it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add to the answer in case anyone else has the same problem.

I had this: **wrong**

```
/*= require reset
 *= require main
 */
```

But I needed to change the first line: **right**

```
/*
 *= require reset
 *= require main
 */
```